# sklearn.feature_selection.chi2 returns list of NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, chi-squared

I have the following dataset (I will upload only a sample of 4 rows, the real one has 15,000 rows):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

quotes=["Sip N Shop Come thru right now Marjais PopularNobodies MMR Marjais SipNShop", 
        "I do not know about you but My family and I will not take the Covid19 vaccine anytime soon",
        "MSignorile Immunizations should be mandatory Period In Oklahoma they will not let kids go to school without them It is dangerous otherwise",
        "President Obama spoke in favor of vaccination for children Fox will start telling its viewers to choose against vaccination in 321"]

labels=[0,1,2,0]
dummy = pd.DataFrame({"quote": quotes, "label":labels})
```

And I want to apply the famous chi square test to eliminate the number of irrelevant words per category (0,1,2). Where 0: neutral, 1: positive, 2: negative.

Below is my approach (similar to the approach implemented [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-with-nlp-tf-idf-vs-word2vec-vs-bert-41ff868d1794)) 
Briefly, I create an empty list of 0's equal to corpus length. 0's represent the first label of y = 0. For the second label (1=positive) I will create an empty list 1's. Similarly for the third label (2=negative).

After applying this 3 times (for each of the target labels), I will then have three 3 lists with the most dependent words per label. This final list will be my new vocabulary for the TF-IDF vectorizer.

```py
def tweeter_tokenizer(tweet):
    return tweet.split(' ')
    
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tweeter_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,2), stop_words=english_stopwords)
vectorizer.fit(dummy["quote"])
X_train = vectorizer.transform(dummy["quote"])
y_train = dummy["label"]

feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
y_neutral     = np.array([0]*X_train.shape[0])
pValue        = 0.90

chi_neutral, p_neutral   = chi2(X_train, y_neutral)

chi_neutral
```

The chi_neutral object is:

> array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan])

At the end I want to create a dataframe equal to the length of unique tokens (feature_names) per label. And I will keep only the words with score > pValue. The dataframe will show me how many from the total tokens of the corpus are dependent to class 0 (neutral). The same approach will be followed for the rest of the labels (1: positive, 2: negative).

```
y_df = np.array([0]*X_train.shape[1])
tokens_neutral_dependent = pd.DataFrame({
    "tweet_token": feature_names,
    "chi2_score" : 1-p_neutral,
    "neutral_label": y_df #length = length of feature_names()
})
tokens_neutral_dependent = tokens_neutral_dependent.sort_values(["neutral_label","chi2_score"], ascending=[True,False])
tokens_neutral_dependent = tokens_neutral_dependent[tokens_neutral_dependent["chi2_score"]>pValue]
tokens_neutral_dependent.shape
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's really meaningful to compute the chi-squared statistic without having the classes attached. The code `chi2(X_train, y_neutral)` is asking "Assuming that class and the parameter are independent, what are the odds of getting this distribution?" But all of the examples you're showing it are the same class.

I would suggest this instead:

```
chi_neutral, p_neutral   = chi2(X_train, y_train)
```

If you're interested in chi-square statistics between particular classes, you can filter the dataset first to just two classes, then run the chi-squared test. But this step is not necessary.

Comment: Hello Nick, thank you for the answer. I have tried to apply the chi square in y_train. But then how do I know which tokens are more important per class. This is what confuses me.

Comment: @NikSp You can filter your data to two classes, and run chi-squared on just a pair of classes. So you can check chi-square statistics between class 0 and class 1. Then you can run chi-squared statistics between class 0 and class 2, and that will tell you how useful it is for that comparison, and so on. But I don't think this step is necessary at all - you're just doing feature selection, right?

Comment: Yeah I have a vocabulary of 143,000 tokens and I want to filter those to only the important ones. Like 5,000 for example. Check also the attached link from the Towards Data Science article I posted. One approach to drastically minimize the number of tokens is to perform chi2 test.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. What I'm saying is that if you run a chi-square test against all classes, you'll see which features are useful for classifying any class. So a word might not be useful for finding the difference between class 0 and class 1, but useful for identifying class 2. Since you're doing feature selection, you don't need to know which words are useful for which class - just which features are unimportant overall.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean when you write "features". And how will I retrieve those "features" after applying the above chi2 test? Are the "features" the corpus quotes? Because the ```chi_neutral, p_neutral``` returned are equal to the number of tokens and not the number of quotes.

Comment: features = tokens. From the article you posted: "we can carry out some Feature Selection, the process of selecting a subset of relevant variables."

Comment: Ok, we are on the same page. Then, I will accept the solution. I asked the question to be sure that I didn't miss something and figure out if my initial approach was correct or wrong.